# How to find if the user changes the Jwt token in react js application with rails backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a doubt in the below condition?

(React and Rails separate application)

I'm saving JWT into the local Storage using the key "token" which sent from the rails server. I find the user in a particular request only through the JWT. What if the user changes the JWT in local storage. How could I handle this case?
If I check login is valid in each request, my server will die?

Any solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you think checking valid login will cause your server to die? It's not that expensive to decode the token, use token to find user and if user found then validate token otherwise send a `403`

Answer (score 0):

The JWT is already asymetrically encrypted when you get it, so the user will be unable to produce a legal JWT without access to the signing key. The client will still be able to decode the JWT and introspect it, however.

The best practice is to use an additional level of symmetric encryption on the server side, using an algorithm like AES. This means that the JWT is encrypted when given to the user, and only decrypted on the server side.

This gives a defense in depth from tampering attacks, as both the secret JWT key and the application's key are necessary to falsify the key. Symmetrically encrypting the JWT also protects information you have stored in it from the client.

Comment: Insightful, but my question is if the user randomly changes, I can understand in rails whether it is a false one, how could I tell frontend application (React) redirect him to login again?